# CSS cross browser centering

Tags: css

I am working on Popup box, I have got a page wherein I click on a button it popups a box. Ths problem is the popup is not in the center of the screen. I have to make the page cross browser compatible.

Here is my code.

CSS:

```
.popup{
    /* css3 drop shadow */
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
       -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    /* css3 border radius */
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
       -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    background:#eee;
    /* styling of the dialog box, i have a fixed dimension for this demo */
    width:50%;
    /* make sure it has the highest z-index */
    clear:both; 
    height:240px;
    position:relative;
    z-index:5000;
    /* hide it by default */
    display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Centered horizontally and vertically:

```
.popup{
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
       -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
       -moz-border-radius: 5px;
            border-radius: 5px;
    background: #eee;
    width: 50%;
    height: 240px;
    z-index: 5000;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-left: -25%;
    margin-top: -120px;
    clear: both;
//    display: none;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AwCWs/

Comment: @user1907680 Great! Please mark as 'best answer' for future users.

Comment: Hey, while loading the page at first, the popup is showing. Instead i want to allow popup to show on button click.

Comment: @user1907680 just uncomment the `display:none;`

Comment: As @deathApril said, just comment `display: none` by removing the `//` Before it. I had commented it out for the sake of the demo.